# Does my style of coding make the Emulator slow?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I am working with Android Studio it runs really smooth. After some time of update. The app was really slow at getting data from the backend (testing backend with PostMan still fast) also execute other tasks. I wonder if our style of coding slow down the app. Have you ever experienced this ? Does the bad coding style has a huge effect on Emulator performance. If yes, could you please suggest a good way of coding that allows the app in Android Studio run faster.
Thank you so much.

Edit: Here is my code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart' hide Image;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Image;
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:goweefrontend/SizeConfig.dart';
import 'package:goweefrontend/View/Detail/DetailJourney.dart';
import 'package:goweefrontend/View/Map/TestMap.dart';
import 'package:goweefrontend/Model/LoggedUser.dart';
import 'package:goweefrontend/View/CustomBottomNavBar/CustomBottomNavBar.dart';
import 'package:goweefrontend/View/UserPage/CustomCalendar.dart';
import 'package:goweefrontend/View/UserPage/JoinRequest.dart';
import 'package:goweefrontend/View/UserPage/UserPageService.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:goweefrontend/View/LoginFunction/LoginComponent/LoginScreen.dart';
import '../../Constants.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../../Model/Journey.dart';

class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = "/userPage";

  @override
  _UserPageState createState() => _UserPageState();
}

class _UserPageState extends State<UserPage> {
  CalendarFormat format = CalendarFormat.twoWeeks;
  DateTime focusedDay = DateTime.now();
  DateTime selectedDay = DateTime.now();
  bool upcomingIsVisible = false;
  bool draftIsVisible = false;
  bool passedIsVisible = false;
  TextEditingController _lastNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _ageController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _phoneNumberController = TextEditingController();
  String _firstName;
  String _lastName;
  int _age;
  String _phoneNumber;
  String _imageURL;
  List<Journey> journeyList = [];
  Future _future;

  Future loadUser() async {
    String jsonString = await storage.read(key: "jwt");
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    loggedUser = new LoggedUser.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    getProfile();
  }
  //http APIs

  editProfile(
      String lastName, String firstName, String age, String phoneNumber) async {
    await UserPageService().editProfile(lastName, firstName, age, phoneNumber);
  }

  getProfile() async {
    var res = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("$baseUrl/users/${loggedUser.user.userId}"),
      headers: {
        'Content_Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${loggedUser.token}',
        'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'
      },
    );
    var data = jsonDecode(res.body);
    loggedUser.user.firstName = data["firstName"];
    loggedUser.user.lastName = data["lastName"];
    loggedUser.user.age = data["age"];
    loggedUser.user.phoneNumber = data["phoneNumber"];
    loggedUser.user.userAvatar.imageLink = data["userAvatar"]["imageLink"];
    setState(() {
      _firstName = data["firstName"];
      _lastName = data["lastName"];
      _age = data["age"];
      _phoneNumber = data["phoneNumber"];
      _imageURL = data["userAvatar"]["imageLink"];
    });
  }

  getJourneyByUserId() async {
    setState(() {
      journeyList = [];
    });
    var res = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("$baseUrl/journeys/userid=${loggedUser.user.userId}"),
      headers: {
        'Content_Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${loggedUser.token}',
        'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'
      },
    );
    var data = jsonDecode(res.body);
    List idList = [];
    for (var i in data) {
      idList.add(i["journeyId"]);
    }
    for (var i in idList) {
      var res = await http.get(
        Uri.parse("$baseUrl/journeys/$i"),
      );
      var data = jsonDecode(res.body);
      Journey userJourney = new Journey.fromJson(data);
      setState(() {
        journeyList.add(userJourney);
      });
    }
    return journeyList;
  }

  logOut() async {
    await UserPageService().logOut();
    setState(() {
      rangeList.clear();
      journeyList.clear();
    });
  }

  Future functionForBuilder() async {
    return await getJourneyByUserId();
  }

  //function to print Journey Card
  Widget printCard(Journey journey, IconData flexIcon, page, visible) {
    return Visibility(
      visible: visible,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
            child: Container(
              height: getHeight(0.1),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 0, 10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        offset: Offset(0, 8),
                        blurRadius: 5,
                        color: Colors.grey[300]),
                  ]),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    //show journey image
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(journey
                                  .images[0].imageLink !=
                              null
                          ? journey.images[0].imageLink
                          : "assets/images/Travel-WordPress-Themes.jpg.webp"),
                      radius: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: getWidth(0.02)),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: getWidth(0.32),
                            child: AutoSizeText(
                              "${journey.departure} - ${journey.destination}",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: getWidth(0.05)),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: getWidth(0.27),
                            child: AutoSizeText(
                              "${journey.startDate.day}/${journey.startDate.month} - "
                              "${journey.endDate.day}/${journey.endDate.month}/${journey.endDate.year}",
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 13),
                              maxLines: 1,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: getWidth(0.05)),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: getWidth(0.1),
                        child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page));
                          },
                          child: FittedBox(
                            child: Icon(
                              flexIcon,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  //function to show dialog User Profile Card
  showDialogFunc1(context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 270),
                height: getHeight(0.4),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 30, 0, 10),
                    child: Row(children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              printInfo("NAME", "$_lastName $_firstName"),
                              printInfo("AGE", "$_age"),
                              printInfo("PHONE", "$_phoneNumber"),
                              Center(
                                child: Container(
                                  height: getHeight(0.05),
                                  decoration: kBoxDecorationView,
                                  child: TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      showDialogFunc2(context);
                                    },
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Edit Profile",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ]),
                        flex: 5,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 40, 0),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 35,
                                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                        loggedUser.user.userAvatar.imageLink),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 15),
                                  FittedBox(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "${loggedUser.user.email}",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          letterSpacing: 1.0,
                                          decoration: TextDecoration.none),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        flex: 5,
                      )
                    ]))),
          ]);
        });
  }

  //print User Information
  printInfo(info1, info2) {
    return FittedBox(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text(
            info1 + " : " + info2,
            style: TextStyle(
              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget loopPrintUpComeTrip() {
    int counter = 0;
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (var i in journeyList) {
      if (i.status == "Upcoming") {
        counter += 1;
        if (counter == 1) {
          list.add(printCard(i, Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              DetailsJourneyScreen(journey: i), true));
        } else {
          list.add(printCard(i, Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              DetailsJourneyScreen(journey: i), upcomingIsVisible));
        }
      }
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
      list.add(Text("No Upcoming Trip to show"));
    }
    return Column(children: list);
  }

  Widget loopPrintInProgressTrip() {
    int counter = 0;
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (var i in journeyList) {
      if (i.status == "In progress") {
        counter += 1;
        if (counter == 1) {
          list.add(printCard(i, Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              DetailsJourneyScreen(journey: i), true));
        } else {
          list.add(printCard(i, Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              DetailsJourneyScreen(journey: i), draftIsVisible));
        }
      }
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
      list.add(Text("No In Progress Trip to show"));
    }
    return Column(children: list);
  }

  Widget loopPrintFinishedTrip() {
    int counter = 0;
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (var i in journeyList) {
      if (i.status == "Finished") {
        counter += 1;
        if (counter == 1) {
          list.add(printCard(i, Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              DetailsJourneyScreen(journey: i), true));
        } else {
          list.add(printCard(i, Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              DetailsJourneyScreen(journey: i), passedIsVisible));
        }
      }
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
      list.add(Text(
        "No Finished Trip to show",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
      ));
    }
    return Column(children: list);
  }

  //print edit form
  printFormField(info, controller) {
    return Container(
      height: getHeight(0.06),
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: TextField(
          controller: controller,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "New $info",
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5, 0, 5),
            isDense: true,
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: kTextColor),
              gapPadding: 0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //show dialog edit profile
  showDialogFunc2(context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 270),
                height: getHeight(0.4),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 30, 0, 10),
                    child: Row(children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                            //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              printFormField("Last Name", _lastNameController),
                              printFormField(
                                  "First Name", _firstNameController),
                              printFormField("Age", _ageController),
                              printFormField(
                                  "Phone Number", _phoneNumberController),
                              SizedBox(height: getHeight(0.01)),
                              Center(
                                  child: Container(
                                height: getHeight(0.05),
                                decoration: kBoxDecorationView,
                                child: TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    await editProfile(
                                        _lastNameController.text,
                                        _firstNameController.text,
                                        _ageController.text,
                                        _phoneNumberController.text);
                                    _lastNameController.clear();
                                    _firstNameController.clear();
                                    _ageController.clear();
                                    _phoneNumberController.clear();
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                    setState(() {
                                      getProfile();
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Save",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ))
                            ]),
                        flex: 6,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 40, 0),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 35,
                                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                        loggedUser.user.userAvatar.imageLink),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                                  Text(
                                    "Upload Image",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 10,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        letterSpacing: 1.0,
                                        decoration: TextDecoration.none),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        flex: 4,
                      )
                    ]))),
          ]);
        });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadUser();
    _future = getJourneyByUserId();
  }

  //screen
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: kColorPalette4,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "User Profile",
            style: TextStyle(color: kColorPalette4),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
          elevation: 0.0,
          titleSpacing: 1.0,
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        Text("Loading...")
                      ]),
                );
              } else {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Center(
                            //user avatar
                            child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            showDialogFunc1(context);
                            getProfile();
                          },
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_imageURL != null
                                ? _imageURL
                                : "https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/256-2560208_person-icon-black-png-transparent-png.png"),
                            radius: 50,
                          ),
                        )),
                        SizedBox(height: 5),
                        CustomCalendar(),
                        Text("Trip Requests",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: kBackgroundColor,
                                letterSpacing: 1.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 15)),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        JoinRequest(),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: getWidth(0.35),
                              child: AutoSizeText(
                                "Upcoming Trips",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: kColorUpComing,
                                    letterSpacing: 1.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 15),
                                maxLines: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Container(
                                height: getHeight(0.05),
                                decoration: kBoxDecorationView,
                                child: TextButton(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "View All",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: kColorPalette4),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      upcomingIsVisible = !upcomingIsVisible;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        //upcoming trip card
                        SizedBox(height: 5),
                        loopPrintUpComeTrip(),
                        //Calendar Field
                        SizedBox(height: 5),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: getWidth(0.35),
                              child: AutoSizeText(
                                "Finished Trips",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: kColorFinished,
                                    letterSpacing: 1.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 15),
                                maxLines: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Container(
                                height: getHeight(0.05),
                                decoration: kBoxDecorationView,
                                child: TextButton(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "View All",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: kColorPalette4),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      passedIsVisible = !passedIsVisible;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 5),
                        loopPrintFinishedTrip(),
                        SizedBox(height: 5),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: getWidth(0.35),
                              child: AutoSizeText(
                                "In Progress Trips",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: kColorInProgress,
                                    letterSpacing: 1.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 15),
                                maxLines: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Container(
                                height: getHeight(0.05),
                                decoration: kBoxDecorationView,
                                child: TextButton(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "View All",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: kColorPalette4),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () => setState(
                                      () => draftIsVisible = !draftIsVisible),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 5),
                        loopPrintInProgressTrip(),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: getHeight(0.055),
                              decoration: kBoxDecorationView,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    await logOut();
                                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                LoginScreen()));
                                  },
                                  child: FittedBox(
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(
                                          Icons.logout,
                                          color: kColorPalette4,
                                          size: 20,
                                        ),
                                        AutoSizeText(
                                          "Log Out",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: kColorPalette4,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: getHeight(0.01),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Style of coding won't slow your program down. However, an inefficient algorithm will.

Comment: In case the system say too much work on the main thread, is it because of my code or the data returned from backend is too big ?

Comment: Without seeing your code and knowing what your code does, there is no way for us to know

Comment: It seems like you're doing most of your tasks on the main thread. We can't however confirm it without looking into your code. I would suggest editing your question to be more specific

Comment: I have a file named UserPage. If I put all of my function (both the functions to render UI and functions to get data from the backend) inside it.  Did I made a mistake of doing too much work on main thread ? In case I move my UI rendering functions to separated classes. Will having too much build() function affect my app performance ?

Comment: I also edited my post by adding the code. Please have a look. Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 0):

Usually when i'm dealing with retrieving and sending data to the database I create a new thread to do the job of transferring data, if you are transferring with the main thread it's not recommended to do that the program could crash.

There is a way to see the performance of the app:
[Profile your app performance](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile)

Another reason to be lagging could be:

> Style of coding won't slow your program down. However, an inefficient
> algorithm will. –  Learning Mathematics  8 hours ago

another reason could be the version of the Android you are using to operate in the app some View object has specific limitations depending of the version of the Android.